# How to get current time in Pacific Timezone when import pytz fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, pytz

I'm working in an environment (AWS Lambda) where `import pytz` doesn't work.

The environment is set to UTC.

How can I get the current time in the U.S. Pacific Timezone in this environment?

I need something simple, and low-maintenance. Somehow forcing `import pytz` to work would be ideal, and I hope to avoid having to copy the entire pytz library into my own script.

*Details*

What have I tried so far? I tried using `import pytz`, and it failed with module not found.

Example code? I tried this, straight from another question on SO:

```
import pytz

eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
utc = pytz.utc
test = '2013-03-27 23:05'
```

Comment: You can set variable in environment (shell), named TZ

Comment: @Romeo Ninov Could that be somehow specified within the script?

Comment: Please check this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301493/setting-timezone-in-python

Comment: You shouldn't have to copy it into your script.  Just put it in your [deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have access to `pytz` in your environment, maybe you have access to `python-dateutil`. In that case you can do:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.tz

eastern = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
datetime.datetime.now(tz=eastern)
```